бандл liip_imagine в symfony: webp и размеры файлов картинок
Хочу сделать генерацию webp копий моих картинок.
В twig шаблоне подключаю это так:
<img class="catalog-about__img mb-25 mb-md-40"
  src="{{ 
    asset('build/images/tmp/_catalog-about/catalog-about.png') | 
    imagine_filter('single_images') 
  }}">

конфиг такой ( /config/packages/liip_imagine.yaml ):
liip_imagine:
  # valid drivers options include "gd" or "gmagick" or "imagick"
  driver: "gd"
  resolvers:
    default:
      web_path: ~
  controller:
    redirect_response_code: 302
  webp:
    generate: true
    quality: 100
  twig:
    mode: 'lazy'
  filter_sets:
    cache: ~
    single_images:
      quality: 100
...

так-то работает и генерится webp, но сам вопрос:
помимо webp создается копия png картинки, которая раз в 20 тяжелее оригинала. Как сделать что бы копия оригинала была такой же по весу как и сам оригинал? А то вдруг попадется браузер, не поддерживающий webp и будет грузится эта толстая копия...
ps

оригинальная картинка лежит в build/images/tmp/_catalog-about/catalog-about.png и весит 132kb
сгенеренная png копия проявляется в media/cache/single_images/build/images/tmp/_catalog-about/ и весит уже 2.6 Mb (webp версия там же и укладывается в 90 kb )

ps2 docker-контейнеры этого сайта на linux работают и какой-нить IE проверить не знаю как

https://symfony.com/bundles/LiipImagineBundle/current/configuration.html
тут есть что почти решает вопрос.
А именно:
  single_images:
    quality: 100
    png_compression_level: 9

для png-шек решает вопрос. Они лишь в 2 раза толше оригинала.
А с учетом того, что webp большинство браузеров поддерживают, решение мне зайдет
